# How to reverse every other sublist of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with sublists `list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}`. I would like to reverse every other sublist, starting from the second one. The result would look like `result = {{1, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 6}, {8, 7}}`. What would be a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `MapAt`, which accepts the same syntax as `Part`:

```
MapAt[Reverse, list, {2 ;; ;; 2}]
(* {{1, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 6}, {8, 7}} *)
```

Answer (score 14):

Using `Part` and `Span` might not seem overly elegant but it is fast:

```
list = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100000, 10}];

a = MapAt[Reverse, list, {2 ;; ;; 2}]; // RepeatedTiming // First

b = ReplacePart[list, i_?EvenQ :> Reverse@list[[i]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First

c = Module[{result = list},
     result[[2 ;; ;; 2]] = list[[2 ;; ;; 2, -1 ;; 1 ;; -1]];
     result
     ]; // RepeatedTiming // First

a == b == c
```

> 0.11
>
> 0.317
>
> 0.0036
>
> True

Comment: A bit cleaner, s/b comparable in speed: `Riffle[list[[;; ;; 2]], list[[2 ;; ;; 2, -1 ;; 1 ;; -1]]]`

Answer (score 7):

Another method is to use [`ReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html):

```
ReplacePart[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}},
    i_ ? EvenQ :> Reverse@list[[i]]
]
(* {{1,2},{4,3},{5,6},{8,7}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

This will work

````
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};

Table[If[EvenQ[i], Reverse[list[[i]]], list[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[list]}]

(*{{1, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 6}, {8, 7}}*)
```
````

Answer (score 4):

**Using `SubsetMap`:**

and repeating the same tests as @HenrikSchumacher,

```
list = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100000, 10}];

d = SubsetMap[Map@Reverse, list, Range[2, Length@list, 2]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First

a == b == c == d
```

> ```
> 0.0924938
> 0.282467
> 0.00579637
> 0.0176473
>
> True
> ```

which is nearest to the existing best solution.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is as follows:

```
If[SameQ[EvenQ[Keys[#]], True], Reverse[#[[2]]], #[[2]]] & /@ Thread[Ordering[list] -> list]

(*{{1, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 6}, {8, 7}}*)
```

Or using `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[If[SameQ[EvenQ[#1],True],Reverse[#2],#2] &, {Range[Length[list]],list}]

(*{{1, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 6}, {8, 7}}*)
```

Or using `KeyValuePattern`, `ReplaceList` and `ReplacePart`:

```
ReplacePart[list, ReplaceList[Thread[list -> Ordering[list]], 
KeyValuePattern[{x_List -> y_?EvenQ}] :> (y -> Reverse[x])]]

 (*{{1, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 6}, {8, 7}}*)
```

Another way using `MatchQ` and `KeyValuePattern`:

```
If[MatchQ[{#}, KeyValuePattern[{x_List -> y_?EvenQ}]] === True, 
   Reverse@#[[1]], #[[1]]] & /@ Thread[list -> Ordering[list]]

(*{{1, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 6}, {8, 7}}*)
```

**Edit**: An additional variant, courtesy of @Syed, is as follows:

```
MapIndexed[If[EvenQ@First@#2, Reverse@#, #] &, list]

(*{{1, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 6}, {8, 7}}*)
```

Comment: `e = MapIndexed[If[EvenQ@First@#2, Reverse@#1, #1] &, list]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First` results in `0.224082` where the `list` is the same as in my post above suggested by @Henrik, so it is considerably worse than other options. Being a built-in function, one expects `MapIndexed` to be more performant and let's hope that it will improve in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In v13.1, [`ReplaceAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAt.html) may be used:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}};

ReplaceAt[list,{x_,y_}:>{y,x}, 2;;;;2]

ReplaceAt[list,x_:>Reverse[x], 2;;;;2]

(*
  {{1, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 6}, {8, 7}}
  {{1, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 6}, {8, 7}}
 *)
```

**Just For Fun**

Specifying part 0 may be used to change the Head of an expression:

```
ReplaceAt[list,_->f,0]

(* f[{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}] *)
```

For example:

```
ReplaceAt[list,_->Times,0]

(* {105, 384} *)  

ReplaceAt[list,_->Times,0]==Times@@list

(* True *)
```